# Is the union of two reservoir samples a random sample?

Tags: sampling

I have two reservoir samples (with replacement) of a distribution which are obtained independently. If I just produce the union of these two samples, will the resulting sample also be considered as a random sample?

Comment: +1 for mentioning "reservoir samples", which caused me to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The union of two independent random samples will also be a random sample. But why count the intersection only once? Using both samples together is also a random sample and has a larger sample size.

Comment: Actually, the union is not an iid sample since possible values only appear at most once.